# How to search on elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I use elasticseach to seach and architecture of each index is

```
{
    "law_id" : "law_id",
    "articles": [
        {
            "article_id" : "article_id",
            "title": "title of article",
            "text": "content of article"
        },
        {
            other article.....
        }
    ]
}
```

How i can search for "text" or "title" and "_source" on result has only "law_id" and "article_id" which "title" or "text" satisfy and doesn't have other "article_id".

Please help me!
Thank you very much!

I tried some queries on the internet. But they were wrong.